# Pull data from email to display on webpage

Tags: php, html, web

I'm an amateur web developer and am working with a local municipality to make a website for their town. I've googled my way through hacking together a good enough product that they're happy, but I've hit a problem.

They want to be able to post minutes from town meetings on the site. The staff of three at the city hall has an average age of 65, and they don't even understand the finer points of email, let alone web development. Updating their site each month for the rest of my life doesn't sound like a great solution either.

Can anybody point me towards a script that might be able to parse an email and display that data on a webpage? Or something like that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose so. I doubt that conversation would turn out as planned, though, and the only reason I got the job in the first place was because I had no experience and was the cheapest choice. I'd really rather get this set up properly and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Wordpress and an addon. Sample solutions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email or
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-post-by-mail/

There are a lot of tutorials about it on the web.

Comment: Does Wordpress allow for single-page integration or does it have to be site-wide? I don't really have any experience with it, and the client didn't want the Wordpress logo all over the site ("we don't want to look like we're sponsoring them!"). If this is an easy choice and I can keep it to the one page it'll be fine, though.

Comment: The easiest way is to buy hosting service with an option of installing wordpress from admin panel. Then you just have to configure "post by email" option (for example in jetpack -the 2nd link I posted).The Wordpress logo may be easily erased from the website, however you can leave it on the footer to appreciate someone's effort :) You could do it without a CMS but it's a lot of coding to do on your own. Why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: They purchased hosting from GoDaddy before I got involved. I'm fairly sure there's Wordpress options on their admin panel. I'll check it out later today and give you the answer if everything works out.